# for loop - statement with no effect

Tags: c

For some reason I'm getting an error: `statement with no effect` on this statement.

```
for (j = idx; j < iter; j + increment) {
    printf("from loop idx = %i", (int)idx);
    punc(ctxt, j);
}
```

Comment: Is it really an error? Not a warning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably meant to write `j += increment` instead of `j + increment`.

Comment: thanks that's exactly it. ... I feel ashamed that I didn't caught it. must be tired

Answer (score 5):

I think you meant `j += increment`, as `j + increment` doesn't actually alter `j` or indeed have any side effects at all - it is a statement with no effect, which is what the compiler is telling you

Comment: And it is probably even optimized out by the compiler so it doesn't do anything at all, not even evaluate.

Comment: If `increment` is added to `j` in a forest and nobody hears noise from poor shielding in the on-board soundcard, did it really make a sound?

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
j + increment
```

With

```
j += increment
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that as an error? How cool, I wish my compiler did that. Basically `j + increment` will return the sum of those two, but `j` won't get modified so your loop would probably run forever.

Comment: If you have `gcc`, the `-Werror` option (with `-Wall`) turns warnings to errors; `-Werror=unused-value` turns the specific warning in this question to an error.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear you meant +=, but in the case that isn't true, the 'volatile' qualifier should prevent warnings.